# Finding the optimal area for fitting non-overlapping squares of total area $n$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, geometry, algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have some finite amount of squares whose total area is $n$. What is the smallest number $A$ we can find such that we can always fit the squares (no matter how many there are) with no overlap in a square of area $A$?

If we look at the case where we have $2$ squares of side lengths $\sqrt{n/2}$, then the total area of the squares is $2\sqrt{n/2}^2=n$. Furthermore, it is quite easy to see that the squares both fit without overlap in the large square if and only if its area is greater than $2n$. Therefore, we have $A\ge2n$. Intuitively, it feels like we should have $A=2n$, but I am unable to prove this. Is it actually possible to prove that $A=2n$ or is there a counterexample forthis statement?

Comment: Rescale all the side lengths by dividing by $\sqrt{n}$. Then, we have a finite amount of squares whose total area is $1$, and we want to fit them without overlap in a square of area $2$. This is possible, as answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804263/given-finitely-many-squares-whose-areas-add-up-to-1-show-that-they-can-be-arr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given finitely many squares whose areas add up to $1$, show that they can be arranged without overlaps inside a square of area $2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804263/given-finitely-many-squares-whose-areas-add-up-to-1-show-that-they-can-be-arr) - obtained from ckefa's comment above.